# "We don't have any refiners to show you"

Tags: web-part, search, search-results

When the search keyword doesn't have any matching result in my search center I have this problem:

When I load the page, I get the
message

> Nothing here matches your search

in the Search Results web part and the

> We don't have any refiners to show you

in the Refinement Web Part.

Can you tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: How should it show any refiners when you have no matching results? The refiners are displayed based on what results are returned

Comment: i mean the refiners wep part not exist  in all search center of sharepoint

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying, or how that is present in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is working as designed. You have to have search results to be able to "further refine" the results. The concept is to narrow down the result set based on attributes returned in the results set. No Results = No Refiners

Comment: that's ok , i'm new in sharepoint andi have understood  where is the probleme , thanks  for answer

Comment: Can I get an "Answer" from you? :)

Comment: It is customary when someone answers your question on Stack Exchange that you mark it as an answer.